# How to set different background color for dynamic table row with similar values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

In my application I am in need to set different background color to table row based on similar td value which is dynamic data. I tried to achieve this but I was unable to group the table row with different background color. I have attached the expected result screen-cap along with the fiddle link.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5ft82z2/21/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>roll</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Random number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>73023-04041</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td><span>73023-04042</span></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Name 3</td>
        <td><span>73023-04040</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Name 4</td>
        <td><span>73023-04042</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Name 5</td>
        <td><span>73023-04041</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
    var tdVal = $(this).children().find("span").text();
    var valueColor = $(this).children().find("span").text();
    if (valueColor == tdVal) {
        //alert("if");
        $(this).parent("tr").addClass("trColor");
    }
});
```

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a filter in an each loop:

```js
var $lastChildren = $("tbody td:last-child");  // get all last children
var colourCounter = 1;

$lastChildren.each(function() {                // loop
  var $child = $(this);                        // get the current child
  if (!$child.hasClass('coloured')) {          // check if it has already been coloured
    var testNumber = $child.text();            // if not get the text
    
    var $filtered = $lastChildren.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() === testNumber;    // filter any other children with same text
    })
    
    if ($filtered.length) {
      $filtered.addClass('coloured')                      // add class to say it is colored (and not include in further tests)
        .parent().addClass('trColor' + colourCounter);    // add colour class to row
        
        colourCounter++;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* not sure how you were going to do this colouring - I've used an incremental counter */
.trColor1 {
  background-color:green;
}
.trColor2 {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
.trColor3 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>roll</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>Random number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>73023-04041</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><span>73023-04042</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td><span>73023-04040</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Name 4</td>
      <td><span>73023-04042</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Name 5</td>
      <td><span>73023-04041</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Up-vote. This should be the accepted answer. perfect!! The only thing is we can apply the background-color directly with the random number * some number  instead of class. Because we are not sure how many classes we need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my jsfiddle with working code. You need to give multiple classes in css and assign different colors.

https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/t5ft82z2/58/

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>roll</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Random number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td><span>73023-04041</span></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td><span>73023-04042</span></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Name 3</td>
        <td><span>73023-04040</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Name 4</td>
        <td><span>73023-04042</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Name 5</td>
         <td><span>73023-04041</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
table td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.trColor0 {
    background-color:pink;
}
.trColor1 {
    background-color:red;
}
.trColor2 {
    background-color:blue;
}
.trColor3 {
    background-color:green;
}
.trColor4 {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $("table tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function () {
        var tdVal = $(this).text();
       $("table tr td span").each(function(){
           if(tdVal == $(this).text()){
               $(this).closest("tr").addClass("trColor"+i);
           }
       });
       i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad to help. :) @SRI

Comment: Not sure how this is marking as accepted answer. This solution won't work for dynamic records(check the same solution for more rows) 
 and has some other issues also. Use the developer tool to check how it rendering after execution. you will come to know what i am meaning.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai **SR**I = **S**mit **R**aval

Comment: @zer00ne seriously :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at following a piece of code as well.

Basically, I am creating an object with desired keys with respective Colors associated with them.

```js
 var colorMap = {};
 $("table tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function () {
    var tdVal = $(this).find("span").text();
       //alert(tdVal);
            
       if(checkItemExist(tdVal,colorMap) == false)
         colorMap[tdVal] = 'trColor'+ (Object.keys(colorMap).length+1)+'';
         
         //alert(JSON.stringify(colorMap));
        
            $(this).parent("tr").addClass(colorMap[tdVal]);
    });
    
    function checkItemExist(item,array){
    
     for (var k in array){
      if (k == item){
                return true;
      }
  } 
        
        return false;
    //colorMap.indexOf(tdVal) == -1
    }
```

```css
table td{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.trColor1{
  background-color:pink;
}
.trColor2{
 background-color:red; 
}
.trColor3{
 background-color:green; 
}
.trColor4{
 background-color:blue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th>roll</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>Random number</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Name 1</td>
<td><span>73023-04041</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Name 2</td>
<td><span>73023-04042</span></td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Name 3</td>
<td><span>73023-04040</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>Name 4</td>
<td><span>73023-04042</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>Name 5</td>
<td><span>73023-04041</span></td>
</tr>



</table>
```